# Несовместимы \ не совместимы

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные

Дословная формулировка "нейростимуляторы не( )совместимые с МРТ". Слитно или раздельно?
По моим ощущениям должно быть слитно, но конкретного правила для этого случая не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Обычное используется слитное написание: **несовместимы с чем-либо**, но и раздельное тоже встречается (частотность в Нацкорпусе 286:29).

***Несовместимый*** ― прилагательное, так как образована от глагола совершенного вида ***совместить*** и страдательным причастием настоящего времени быть не может.

Поэтому написание НЕ должно соответствовать правилам для прилагательных, на которые "не действуют" зависимые слова.

**Правда, бывают исключения.**

Так, **при усилении отрицания** написание раздельное: Деньги, власть, положение и чувства, которые никак не совместимы друг с другом.

Иногда учитывается правило Розенталя,согласно которому прилагтельные **могут быть сближены с причастиями:** http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

8. **Раздельное написание частицы не с прилагательным, имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, встречается:**
   1) при прилагательных, которые в полной и краткой формах имеют разное значение: не готовый к выходу актёр; не склонный к простуде ребёнок;

3) при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами после определяемого существительного (иногда): Шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле. — Это черты, не свойственные нашей молодёжи.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, оба варианта разрешены правилами. Факт, что оба встречаются в Нацкорпусе. Если вы в опредленном контексте сможете определить, что вам больше подходит, наличие несовместимости или отсутствие совместимости, то Вам не составит труда решить, писать слитно или раздельно.